# SUMIF with phone's area code and wildcard * being the criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Trying to perform SUMIF on a range of rows in a column if they meet the criteria. For example, I want to sum up the rate for all rows that contain area code 212 in column A.

I tried to the following formula at the start:

> =SUMIF(A:A,"212*",B:B)

Also tried to set column A to text/general/number formats. Tried using the &("212"&"*" and 212&"*"). None of those SUMed values up.

```
      A          B
+------------+-------+
| Call       | Rate  |
+------------+-------+
| 2125689034 | 0.050 |
| 3478568843 | 0.045 |
| 7182511265 | 0.047 |
| 2128603619 | 0.050 |
| 7180530692 | 0.046 |
+------------+-------+
```

Comment: Look into using pivot tables and watch your jaw drop when you see how easy and powerful they are.

Comment: With your formula, go into your A cells, and hit `F2` then Enter.  I did that and the `SumIf()` correctly output the answer. I don't know why it didn't do that before "re-entering the cell". I suspect it's the cell type or how Excel's reading them.

Comment: The problem is that the phone numbers are *numbers* and not *text* so you'll have to treat them as numbers in your formula.  If you must use `SUMIF`: `=SUMIF(A:A,">=2120000000",B:B)-SUMIF(A:A,">=2130000000",B:B)` and if you have Excel 2007 or higher you can use `SUMIFS`: `=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">=2120000000",A:A,"<2130000000")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT($A$2:$A$6,3)="212")*B2:B6)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Would it be an easy tweak if you wanted to find "212" anywhere in the cell? Or would that pretty much change the formula/logic altogether?

Comment: @BruceWayne `=SUMPRODUCT((ISNUMBER(SEARCH("212",$A$2:$A$6)))*B2:B6)`

Comment: @ScottCraner Says #VALUE(error in value) in the cell with the formula.

Comment: @Ion try the edit.  If that does not work, then you have errors and or text in the range `B2:B6`

Comment: @ScottCraner That's better but the resulting value is very bloated. SUM should be about $60.0 but get $450,000.0

Comment: Show the formula you are using. @Ion

Comment: @ScottCraner I think I realized what my mistake was just now. I'll check the end results thoroughly.

Comment: Would it be an easy tweak if you wanted to find `21` _and_ `2` anywhere in the cell? =P Edit: I guess you'd just add an `and` to the `search`?

Comment: @findwindow so simply even you could do it. ;P

Comment: You overestimate my knowledge XD